# Why are the rows in my Bootstrap grid overlapping?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hoping someone can help me figure out what I am missing. Right now, the rows are overlapping. I want the two rows to be spaced out appropriately, based off of the size of the images (they are all same size). I have no idea what I am missing to make this respond the way I want it to.

[Code](https://codepen.io/brianpensinger/pen/MvWVVr)

```css
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .gallery-project-thumb {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .vert-pad {
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .gallery-project-thumb img:first-child {
        border: 8px solid #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0.5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px .5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0.5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .gallery-project-thumb img:nth-child(2) {
        z-index: 2;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        border: 8px solid #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        position: absolute;
        -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
        transform: rotate(-2deg);
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .gallery-project-thumb img:nth-child(3) {
        z-index: 1;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        border: 8px solid #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        position: absolute;
        -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
        transform: rotate(2deg);
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row vert-pad gallery-project-container" style="margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 20px;">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="gallery-project-thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="gallery-project-thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="gallery-project-thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="gallery-project-thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row vert-pad gallery-project-container" style="margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 20px;">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="gallery-project-thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="gallery-project-thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="gallery-project-thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="gallery-project-thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"> <img class="gallery-project-thumb-background" src="https://via.placeholder.com/840x560"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you absolutely positioning the images? If you take out the absolute positions, does that solve your problem?

Comment: I am needing those background images for the "photo stack effect", I believe. Not sure of another way to replicate that effect.

Comment: Got it, and I assume you don't want to just increase the bottom-padding on the row?

Comment: I think that would work but it wouldn't be responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the images are being absolutely positioned, the browser doesn't know how tall to make those element. If you set a height to the .gallery-project-thumb  class as the height of the image you should be set

```
.gallery-project-thumb{
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This works. I wanted to avoid adding a static height but maybe the way I have it set up, I have to? I set the height to vw units, so its a little more responsive. Thanks!

Comment: You could try separating out the first img in the stack to its own div and make that one relatively positioned to establish the height and then absolutely position the others on top of it.